Deploying a spartacus application automatically in Azure cloud
We have a common code base which can be used for multiple businesses and we are in the process of simplifying their onboarding process so that they can launch business portal online ASAP.
Here are the steps to make it more clear
1.Present the form(assume the application hosting this form is running in different server) to bew business that is onboarding to provide their business name, git repo url to be used(same code base)  etc
2.The data submitted should pull the git repo code which is already built for existing business and spin up new instance automatically in azure and deploy the code in azure and start up the server of the new application and launch the application (assumption is the URL of the new application is a configurable in the above form instep 1)
3.Is this use case possible in terms of automating these steps from once the form submitted in step 1 we use   Azure dev ops for code  repo and have azure subscription .
Kindly advise how this can be achieved.

I noticed there is a blog may be helpful for you Automatically Deploying the Spartacus Application in Azure Cloud: Simplifying Onboarding for Multiple Businesses.
"The data submitted should pull the git repo code which is already built for existing business" - You can specify events to trigger the pipeline to build or deploy your app. If the git repo you want to pull isn't the current one, you can define a repositories resource and check out multiple repositories in your pipeline.
To deploy an app to Azure App service, you can use task AzureWebApp@1. Refer to this doc Deploy to App Service using Azure Pipelines for the detailed info.
